# How to execute 'npm link' directly on install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json, npm-link

I have an internal project where I want to link a command to a file with `bin`. Like expect this `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "bin": {
    "cli-name": "./bin/my-executable.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-red": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

When executing `npm install`, all dependencies will be installed, and the `bin` configuration of `node-red` will be created too.

But my own `bin` will be completely ignored. It's not possible to use `cli-name` in `cmd`. It's necessary to execute `npm link` too, in a second step. Then `cli-name` will be available as command in console. I've even tried to use a `postinstall` script of `npm` with `npm link` in it, but then I got a loop ...

Is there a way to do this in one step on `npm install`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems actually no build-in way to execute this tasks togeter automatically. So I've created an request for this feature directly to `npm`. It seems that a new command like `npm il` could be implemented.

I will updates this here when this or another way is available.

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/15999

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing you `package.json` to something like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "script": {
    "cli-name": "./bin/my-executable.js",
    "postinstall": "npm run cli-name"
  },
  "dependencies": {
     "node-red": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

And just run:

```
npm install
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not what I was looking for. I need an own registered name for this, and not the execution of a script by npm. I want the same result as running `npm link`.

Comment: my bad, did not understand that part

Comment: @eisbehr is there a reason you cannot use `npm link` as the `postinstall` script? `postinstall` is executed after `install` automatically by npm.
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts
Edit: I see that you end up in an infinite loop, as do I.

Comment: This answer actually helped for an unrelated question :)

Answer (score 1):

npm-link is for a different purpose really. The moment you do npm install, you should be able to use it in the command line already.

npm link is for linking your current development folder to the installed directory of your package. This is so that, as you are making changes in your development folder, it is been automatically avaliable on the cli and you do not have to re-install.

After installing, try going to usr/local/bin <- This is where it should be. if you cannot find my-executable.js here. Then something is wrong along that installation process.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run a `global` binary (`bin`) module you need to install it globally.

`npm -g install`

https://bretkikehara.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/nodejs-creating-your-first-global-module/

Another option (if you're on linux) is to use `$(npm bin)/<module>` if it is not installed globally.

Comment: Thank your for your feedback. But I think it's not the best advice to install everything globally just for link binaries (I've even not tested if this works). And `npm link` will work without global installation too. So I was hoping for a better way ...

Comment: You can run the binaries without `-g`, that's just the easiest way to do it, `$(npm bin)` will resolve the binary without it being installed globally.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised that all the other answers are basically wrong. To avoid a loop, simply:

```js
"preinstall": "npm link"
```

Comment: This worked for me! Maybe this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script in your `package.json` to do both tasks in one command like so:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "bin": {
    "cli-name": "./bin/my-executable.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "install-link": "npm install && npm link my-project"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-red": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Then just run `npm run install-link`, and it will run both commands.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. But this is exactly what I didn't want to have.

Comment: If this isn't what you want and `postinstall` won't work for you, I think your only option here, that is if you "insist" on modifying the behaviour of `npm install`, is to fork the [npm](https://github.com/npm/npm) repo and make your changes there, or create a pull request, and become a contributor. Seems like overkill though just to be able chain commands/functionality together.

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm ln`. An alias to `npm link` by npm documentation, worked for me on PowerShell 5.

[npm-link documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).